# Mocking Controller Action Method which use 'RouteData.Values' in dot net 6 using MOQ and Xunits

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq, xunit

Sorry for long piece of code but I have tried my best to make it as simple as possible:
I have an action method which I am trying to mock:

```
public IActionResult Get(long siteId)
    {
        //Get all the Reports
        var countryCode = (string)this.RouteData.Values["CountryCode"];
        var microMarketReport = _microMarketPriceOverviewBusiness.GetMicroMarketOverviewReport(siteId, countryCode).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        return Ok(microMarketReport);
    }
```

The Test method is as follows:

```
[Fact]
    public void Get_OK()
    {
        // Arrange
        MockMicroMarketPriceOverviewBusiness.Setup(x => x.GetMicroMarketOverviewReport(It.IsAny<long>(),It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(Task.Run(() => new MicroMarketOverviewModel()));
        var unitUnderTest = CreateMicroMarketPriceOverviewController();

        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("CountryCode", "DE");            

        // Act
        var result = (OkObjectResult)unitUnderTest.Get(120);

        // Assert
        Assert.True(result.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status200OK);
    }
```

CreateMicroMarketPriceOverviewController which is used inside the Fact is as follows:

```
private MicroMarketPriceOverviewController CreateMicroMarketPriceOverviewController()
    {
        var context = new DefaultHttpContext();
        
        context.Request.Headers.Add("X-Correlation-ID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        
        var controllerContext = new ControllerContext()
        {
            HttpContext = context.HttpContext
        };

        context.HttpContext.Request.Path = PathString.FromUriComponent(new Uri("http://localhost/api/v1/{CountryCode}/[controller]"));
        context.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteValueDictionary() { { "CountryCode", "NL" } };
        return new MicroMarketPriceOverviewController(MockMicroMarketPriceOverviewBusiness.Object, mockLogger);
    }
```

When I Run my test the line 'var countryCode = (string)this.RouteData.Values["CountryCode"]' inside the action method throws following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What Am I doing wrong even after I am setting the RouteData value??.